# Remove cart MAgento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

Is there a way to hide cart if an item is empty and show it when there is product added to cart without reloading the page?

Thank you.

Comment: Donot understand?what you mean by remove cart?

Comment: I mean I will hide these http://prntscr.com/l498mu when there is no item on cart, and display it when there product added to cart without reloading the page.

Comment: Do you mean that if there is no item in cart then you want to hide the cart icon and when there is any item in cart you want to show the cart icon. Is that you want?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all the response. Just got it fixed. I just created a script on it to hide the cart icon when there is no item.